# Register with a username using Ruby on Rails Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Devise Gem, I was able to sign in and register via email, but how can I login with username?How can I add validation to a username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check devise wiki, should be enough to solve this.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address